# Able to call REST API protected with SSL (HTTPS) from Postman client, but not able to call from java code

Tags: java, security, ssl, pkix

I have a 3rd party service that I need to make a REST call to from my java application, the rest api uses a client certificate-based authentication, and for using the API the 3rd party team has provided us with .cer and .key files. When I add these .cer and .key files in postman client certificates, i am able to call the API and get a response
[image]

However, when trying to import the client certificate in java truststore(jre/lib/security/cacert) or loading the certificate in custom ssl context and then trying to make the call from my java application using a http client gives me the following exception -

```
 PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I, first of all, created a pkcs12 certificate (.p12) using openssl command, using the cer and the key file.

```
pkcs12 -export -in C:\cert\abc.cer -inkey C:\certs\abc.key -out abc.p12 -name test
```

then tried to import the p12 file in my java code to create a custom restTemplate -

```
@Configuration
public class CustomConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException,
            CertificateException, MalformedURLException, IOException {

        SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
                .loadTrustMaterial(new URL("file:src/main/resources/abc.p12"), "changeit".toCharArray()).build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslConFactory).build();
        ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

        return restTemplate;

    }
}
```

prior to this I also tried to add this p12 cert to a new java keystore (jks) file and imported it to my system's java cacert, however, i still keep getting the same PKIX path building failed error.
What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Does `abc.p12` also contain intermediate and root certs?

A single source of truth, so to speak.

And the JVM itself is configured to use it as a trust store too?

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=abc.p12 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

I ask, because the JVM isn't recognizing the root CA, and that is why it can't build the chain.

Comment: No, they are not self-signed certificates, it has a intermediate issuer and root CA certificate

Comment: OK, it was a thought.

Comment: OP stated not Self Signed ->  https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/master/httpclient5/src/main/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/ssl/TrustSelfSignedStrategy.java

Comment: pardon me, for I am fairly new to SSL and certificate-based authentication, but when I open the p12 file using the KeyStore explorer GUI application, I am able to see the Certificate Hierarchy which shows the root, intermediate, and server certificates. Does that indicate that its a single source of truth or self contained?

Comment: I'm beginning to think that you haven't told the JVM about the root CA. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: i tried to import the p12 cert into the default java (%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacert) , but that did not work, also added System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", System.getenv("JAVACACERT_PATH")); wherein the JAVACERT_PATH is the same as the above-mentioned path. Finally tried to load the custom SSLcontext as shown in the question. but I keep getting the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252396/discussion-between-soumitra-goswami-and-bill-mair).